# Exclude Azure devops pipeline from running for certain folder in directory

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a project on GitHub that is structured like this:

```
- lib
    - project-1
    - project-2
- project-3
```

I have a build pipeline that I only want to trigger when changes are made to `project-3`. I would like to exclude triggering this pipeline for any other changes (changes to `project-1` and `project-2`). Right now I have the following configuration file:

```yaml
jobs:
  - job: rolling_VS2017_build
    displayName: 'Extensions build'
    pool:
      name: Hosted VS2017
    steps:
      - template: build/sdl-tasks.yml
      - template: build/npm-build-extensions-steps.yml
pr:
    branches: 
      include:
        - '*'
    paths:
      include:
        - project-3/*
      exclude: 
        - '*'
```

Unfortunately, this pipeline is still being triggered for pull requests with changes to any project. How can I edit the yml file to ensure that the pipeline is only run for pull requests that make changes to `project-3`, and that it's not run for any other changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your yaml file on my side, it worked as expected but it also triggered a CI build. Please check the pipeline is triggered by CI or PR:

[image]

And you may add the following syntax in your yaml build:

```
trigger:
  - none
```

Comment: Thanks. `trigger: -none` was what I was looking for.